# http://xmr.llcoins.net/checktx.html tool does not work

Tags: viewkey

I tried to use the view key in the tool :  http://xmr.llcoins.net/checktx.html

But it does not work, after pushing the button it states that it does not get a connection with moneroblocks

Anyone else this problem?

Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a couple of people reported it already. Unfortunately, it's up to the moneroblocks site to resolve the matter or to the author of the webpage (or anyone else, really) to change the service from which the site fetches block info.

Alternatively, you can use [this](https://xmrchain.net/tx/7d73094bfe0497565eb1f9195a8240d043ca5f980fbc5be3e15a88b4355cea87) block explorer to check any TX, as in the linked example. Just find it first and use the interface to input address and viewkey and it will show you the real output and the amount!

Comment: Hi Thx. I'm using the tool. But now I only see appr 1/3 of the send funds coming in on the address. Is this the monero protocol that is cuts the transaction in parts?